# Why do I see a performance drop when using row-major order?

Tags: c, caching, optimization, nested-loops, simd

I have got a piece of code which runs over a large matrix and computes column-wise binned statistics, where the bins are given in a vector b.

The code goes (something) like this:

```
for (item = 0; item < items; item++) {
    uint8 bin = binvec[item];
    for (col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
        int idx = item * items_stride + col * cols_stride;
        uint8 val = matrix[idx];
        float x = matrix2[idx];
        count[bin][val][col] += x;
    }
}
```

Assume that the number of columns is known at compile time.
The values of `matrix` have no specific structure / order - assume pure random values.
the data size is fairly large: a couple of millions of items and hundreds of columns.

Looking at the code, I'd assume the best performance would be achieved when:

1. `matrix` is row major, for better cache locality.
2. `count` would be accessed as `count[bin][col][val]`, so the computation of the address of `count[bin][col]` could be optimized, allowing easier prefetching etc.

However, I got the best performance when creating `matrix` as column-major, and accessing `count` in the order which appears in the code.

Trying to use options (1) or (2) causes a ~50% run time penalty.
This goes against my intuition as to cache locality and compiler optimizations, vectorizations etc.

Any idea as to why? This really baffles me.

Comment: Yes, I would predict that the way you've written the code here would be more optimal, *especially* if the number of columns is a compile-time constant, since the compiler could unroll that loop (to some degree or another). Unfortunately, it's hard for me to investigate this any further without a [mcve]. I can't verify your timing results; I can't analyze the code generated by common compilers; I can't try any of my own optimizations to test their effect. All I can do is say, "Yeah, that's weird." By the way, what is "10x"?

Comment: 10x is thanks :) The loop unrolling could be done regardless of the matrix memory layout and the access to `count`, so I doubt that this is the case. I'll add an example ASAP though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused. In your example matrix is row major. Could you share the both implementations disregarding the count access?

Your inner loop goes over columns so indeed row major would be better with cacheline covering several columns at once.

As for the count, your val depends on what is stored in your matrix while columns are ordered sequentially, so if you access count this way:

```c
count[bin][val][col]
```

You get data from the cache if there are several sequential rows in column with equal val. Accessing it this way though:

```c
count[bin][col][val]
```

You have basically zero chances to get data from cache since you hop way too far after you've incremented your col. This is my best bet at this part.

Is your matrix (the one providing val) as random as you think?

Comment: I'm sorry, should have clarified this a bit. I access the matrix using a linear indexing, knowing the strides for each dimension. Same goes for the access to all matrices. I've fixed the code example accordingly.

Comment: As for the matrix - columns are independently drawn. Each column by itself is a Markov process, with mean of each sample given by the previous sample, so subsequent column entries may be close in value, but are not likely to be the same.

Comment: @Moti So basically in the rows first case you have items_stride == ncols, cols_stride == 1. Approaching the problem from another angle, is it possible to subsample your matrix and run cachegrind to check if it is indeed cache affecting the performance?

Comment: However, There's a chance that there are rows of zeros, which may indeed be more cache-friendly, as you mentioned. I'll take a look , thank you!

Comment: I have no experience with cachegrind, I'll take a look. Many thanks again.

Comment: Turns out that all-zero rows are indeed a lot more common than I expected, which explains the counter-intuitive performance boost when accessing count as shown in the code. Thanks @tgregory